# Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Bash script defaults read generates The domain/default pair of does not exist error

Tags: macos, bash, safari

I am trying to check the default homepage in Safari on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

On my vanilla system the homepage isn't actually set, so first I forcibly set the HomePage using command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari.plist HomePage www.google.co.uk
```

Now I can read the HomePage setting using this command:

```
defaults read com.apple.Safari.plist HomePage
```

www.google.co.uk

is the output.

I need to do this for the console user using a Bash Script that is delivered and executed by Microsoft SCCM.  The Microsoft SCCM Client runs under the machine's system account so running the defaults read command above does not report the logged-in user's setting.  To work around this I am using commands that first determine the logged-in user's userID and then another to read the HomePage value using a full path to the logged-in user's (if applicable) instance of the Safari plist file.

If I execute the top four lines manually, the expected homepage is stored in variable myuserhompage and is displayed as expected.

```
myuser=$(stat -f%Su /dev/console)
myuserhompage="$(defaults read /users/$myuser/library/preferences/com.apple.Safari HomePage)"
if [[ ${myuserhompage} == "www.google.co.uk" ]] ;
then
  echo "homepage_set"
  exit 0
else
  echo "homepage_not_set"
  exit 1
fi
```

However when I run the same lines of code from within a Bash script, I see The domain/default pair of does not exist error.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `defaults read /users/$myuser/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` (replace your userid) directly from command line and from script and compared the results?

Comment: I re-typed the code and have since found it has worked.  That led me on to another issue that I've since resolved and have just updated the question with the amendment.  There must have been a special character or character translation issue because when re-typed the code works as expected from both the command line and via script.

Comment: This is usually a line ending issue. In Windows it is `\r\n` and in unix only `\n`.

Comment: Thanks derlarsschneider

Answer (score 0):

By re-typing the text directly into the OS X VM instead of relying on copy/paste from a Windows host I now appear to get consistency between the terminal command line and scripted commands.  This has resolved my issue.  It also highlighted an issue with the result evaluation which I have updated accordingly. Thanks.